# Rails validation not failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, proc

I have the following validation on a model field:

```
validates :invoice_date, :presence => true, :unless => Proc.new { |invoice| invoice.invoice_date.future? }
```

It looks pretty simple, but it doesn't work. There is no error thrown if the date is in the future. And the `Proc` indeed returns `false` in that case.

Any idea why isn't there any validation error shown?

Comment: You want this to throw error when the date is in future?

Comment: Yes, this is the intended behavior.

Comment: You should also comment the reason for downvote.

Comment: @ShamsulHaque downvote was mine and it was because your first version of answer didn't solve OP's problem at all.

Comment: @MarekLipka if it were not worked then you can notify that it is not working, after that i can change it so that it suits your requirements. otherwise you can downvote it.

Comment: @ShamsulHaque nope, adding explanation for downvote isn't mandatory. I usually do it, but this case was pretty obvious.

Comment: @MarekLipka then how can i know if it worked or not and should i update it or not unless and untill i understand the full requirements.

Comment: @ShamsulHaque You could ask. As you can see, I gave downvote explanation after you explicitly requested for it.

Comment: @MarekLipka thats why i go through the requirements again and changed that way.

Comment: @ShamsulHaque so it turns out my downvote was useful since it motivated you to correct your answer. ;)

Comment: @MarekLipka but now my answer is correct so it should not be voted up ?

Comment: @ShamsulHaque it's correct but comparing to other answers (both was upvoted by me), it lacks some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validates :invoice_date, :presence => true
validate :is_future_invoice_date?

private
 def is_future_invoice_date?
   if invoice_date.future?
     errors.add(:invoice_date, 'Sorry, your invoice date is in future time.')
   end
end
```

Presence true simply ensures, invoice_date must be present. 
for validating whether the date is a future date or not we have specified a custom validation method.(is_future_invoice_date?)
This method, will add error message against our invoice_date attribute if the date is of future date.

More info here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: I think you could elaborate your answer a little bit more. The code is useful, but it doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 3):

The 'unless' condition is for deciding if the validation should run or not, not if it should succeed or fail. So your validation is essentially saying "validate the presence of invoice_date, unless invoice_date is in the future in which case don't validate its presence" (which makes no sense)

It sounds like you want two validations, presence and date fencing.

```
validate :invoice_date_in_past

def invoice_date_in_past
  if invoice_date.future?
    errors.add(:invoice_date, 'must be a date in the past')
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh, the docs were not clear enough on this (at least for me). Thanks for clarifying and for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that :--

```
validate check_invoice_date_is_future

def check_invoice_date_is_future
 if invoice_date.present?
   errors.add(:invoice_date, "Should not be in future.") if invoice_date.future?
 else
   errors.add(:invoice_date, "can't be blank.")
 end
end
```